# tranne che + negazione

Tags: word-meaning, meaning

I read the sentence

> Non posso disturbarle tranne / salvo / eccetto che non sia molto urgente.

illustrating the use of congiuntivo after tranno che.

In other languages, we would say

> I can't disturb him except if this is very urgent.

It would be the same in French or German for instance. I don't really get why there is a negation. Is the english translation above correct and why is there a negation ? Couldn't we say

> Non posso disturbarli tranne che sia molto urgente.

or what would be the sense of this last sentence ?

Comment: (It's *tranne*, not *tranno*.)

Comment: Did you check any Italian dictionary, such as [this](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tranne)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Treccani, **non**](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/non/), definition `e.`:

> Usato **pleonasticamente**, si può trovare [...] dopo le locuz. congiuntive *a meno che, salvo che, eccetto che* e sim.: *per poco non ci riuscivo; dovrò rinunciare all’acquisto, a meno che non mi faccia un prezzo speciale*.

This means that that "non" can be omitted without changing the meaning of the sentence.

> Non posso disturbarle **eccetto che non** sia molto urgente.

and

> Non posso disturbarle **eccetto che** sia molto urgente.

Both translate as

> I cannot disturb *them* unless it is very urgent.

More on this on https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negazione_espletiva - even French uses a similar structure sometimes, for example "*avant que **ne***" + `subjunctive`.